# Input box color not appearing in Firefox

Tags: css, forms, firefox, search-form

I've come across an issue where the input text in my search form seems to be transparent in Firefox only.

The input text appears in Chrome, and in Firefox *(latest stable 40.0.3 on OS X El Capitan 144dpi/retina display)* I can still type in the box, it's just that none of the text is visible.

- I've disabled all the color properties (in inspector) for both the input element and any parent elements it may be inheriting transparency from.
- I've tried applying the `!important` rule to the input box's color (I know this is bad practice), but the text still refuses to appear in Firefox.

I've read other posts where this has been an issue in older versions of Firefox, specifically before Firefox 4, but I don't see why something like this would happen in Firefox 40. Moreover this form works perfectly on other parts of the site.

You can see the search form live [on this page](http://rvr.searchanddevelop.ca/services) (first element in the sidebar).
Note that the same form appears in the footer with slightly different CSS styles and works fine.

*This site is built on the Foundation framework and many base rules are inherited from foundation.css*

Comment: Can't see a sidebar.

Comment: Sorry, I put in the incorrect link. Corrected.

Comment: You're padding takes the whole space, so you can see that text. Remove the `#sidebar #searchform input[type="text"]` and it'll work.

Comment: Thank you. I feel silly for missing that.